# Laravel Livewire, Global scope error after initial request

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I am facing an issue using global scope,
I am working on a multi-tenant application, I need to scope data base on the current tenant/company.
Tenant/Company is in the request which can access like so `request()->company()`

Everything works great with Controllers and Blade, now upgrading my application to Livewire
The scope works very on the first request, I got knock off on a subsequent request with this error

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to App\Tenant\Scope\TenantScope::__construct() must be an instance of 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given, called in 
D:\laragon\www\vistate\app\Tenant\Traits\ForTenants.php on line 19
```

To reproduce this I have the following

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Tenant\Scope;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

    class TenantScope implements Scope
    {
        protected $company;

        public function __construct (Model $company)
        {
            $this->company = $company;
        }

        public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
        {
            return $builder->where($this->company->getForeignKey(), '=', $this->company->id);
        }
    }
```

Livewire Version 2.4.1

Here is my Trait

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Tenant\Traits;

    use App\Tenant\Observers\TenantObserver;
    use App\Tenant\Scope\TenantScope;
    use App\Tenant\Manager;

    trait ForTenants
    {
        public static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            $manager = app(Manager::class);


            static::addGlobalScope(
              new TenantScope($manager->getCompany())
            );

            static::observe(
                app(TenantObserver::class)
            );
        }

    }
```

so basically the active tenant is set in the request so it can be accessed throughout the application like so `request()->company()`
On first load, everything works fine but thereafter ( hydrate) `request()->company()` returns null value

Please any advise heads up how to resolve this

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $company; 
public function __construct (Model $company) 
{ 
      $this->company = $company; 
} 
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) 
{ 
      return $builder->where($this->company->getForeignKey(), '=', $this->company->id); 
}
```

Check this 2 things.
Try change protected to public the company property. In Livewire, as long as I know, protected and private don't persist data.
In the apply method (maybe this is irrelevant but checked instead) you make a comparison to the same company instance

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) 
{ 
      return $builder->where($this->company->getForeignKey(), '=', $this->company->id); 
}
```

I think you need compare the $this->company->getForeignKey(), '=', $model->id, as you are passing $model instance as parameter?

Comment: Thank you @Prospero
the whole logic is working fine with Inertia Js and Controller Blade

we are short of Vue developer in our team which is why we are dropping Inertia Js and going with Livewire. on the other hand livewire is giving and error here, 

On livewire first load the scope will work, if I am just getting data from the database the scope work 
If I use wire:model.defer and submit the form everything works fine but the issue comes if I have to do real time on livewire class

Comment: Put some code of the Livewire component to see how you're handling that